# Multiple inputs feature to train neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am working on a project in which I have **3 features x1, x2, x3** which are **images present in a folder** to train a neural network. I am using **keras** library `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory()` which gives following output:

```
Found 78200 images belonging to 46 classes.
Found 78200 images belonging to 46 classes.
Found 78200 images belonging to 46 classes. 
Found 13800 images belonging to 46 classes.
```

The last one belongs to the test data.
As an example, the file structure of my data would look like this:

```
├── trainingf1
│   ├── Class1
│   │   ├── IMG_1.jpg
│   │   ├── etc.jpg
│   ├── Class2
│   │   ├── IMG_1.jpg
│   │   ├── etc.jpg
├── trainingf2
│   ├── Class1
│   │   ├── IMG_1.jpg
│   │   ├── etc.jpg
│   ├── Class2
│   │   ├── IMG_1.jpg
│   │   ├── etc.jpg
├── trainingf3
│   ├── Class1
│   │   ├── IMG_1.jpg
│   │   ├── etc.jpg
│   ├── Class2
│   │   ├── IMG_1.jpg
│   │   ├── etc.jpg
```

These 3 features are then passed to CNN and the final output is then concatenated and passed into a neural network.

Now I am building the model which I knew will give an error as I am passing a Directory Iterator but I cant find a solution for the same.

To build the model, I am using:

```
model.fit(x=[trainGeneratorf1, trainGeneratorf2, trainGeneratorf3],
    epochs = 25,
    steps_per_epoch = 2444,
    validation_data = validation_generator,
    validation_steps = 432, 
    batch_size=8)
```

Error is: `Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator'>"}), <class 'NoneType'>`

Anyone with any solution so that I can use a directory Iterator and pass it as multiple features.

FYI I am using functional API and not sequential API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass multiples generator to the `fit` method. The generator is supposed to generate the data at the right format. In your case, that would be a nested tuple of the following shape:

```
((img1, img2, img3), (label1, label2, label3))
```

It's hard to modify the DirectoryIterator returned by the `ImageGenerator`, but you can convert it to a `tf.data.Dataset` and use a combination of `zip` and `map` to get the desired outcome. It's not the most efficient approach, but it should work.

Here is an example with two datasets:

```
generator1 = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory("path/to/images/1")
generator2 = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory("path/to/images/2")

ds1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator1.__iter__, (tf.float32, tf.float32))
ds2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator2.__iter__, (tf.float32, tf.float32))

ds_combined = tf.data.Dataset.zip((ds1,ds2)) # output will be ((img1, label1), (img2, label2))
ds_rearranged = ds_combined.map(lambda ds1,ds2: ((ds1[0],ds2[0]),(ds1[1],ds2[1])))
```

Then call `fit` with the dataset:

```
model.fit(ds_rearranged)
```

Comment: Now it gives the following error: `AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-4c183b55a799> in <module>
      1 model.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = "categorical_crossentropy", metrics = ["accuracy"])
      2 
----> 3 res=model.fit_generator(
      4         ds_rearranged,
      5         epochs = 25,

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py in new_func(*args, **kwargs)  AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'`

Comment: Can you add your model definition please?

Comment: `ds_rearranged` is a `MapDataset` while the `fit` method is expecting a numpy array or a tensor. I am trying to change it but all in vein.

Comment: The fit method accept a tf.data.Dataset. I can help you if you share your model definition, I need to check how you defined the inputs. If you don't want to share the full model, share a reduced example

Comment: Here is a jam board link of my model and what I am trying to do [https://jamboard.google.com/d/107DOIunDRxmV4JOKyJIKoCZ7WUVu-Yg3Gd7SgAek2Rw/edit?usp=sharing]. Features f1, f2, f3 (.png format) are present in a directory and divided into 46 classes (folders), the structure of which I have shown above. But the main problem is how should I process the data to fit it in `fit` model.

Comment: The last thing which came to my mind is to use different kernels and use sequential API but it has some problems and it will be better to use functional API.